Automatic Subpartition in Oracle
I have a table which is partitioned on ts_date ( Interval partition) now requirement is to create sub partition on run_id column which is being populated from sequence.
For one ts_date there may be 10 run_ids.
Problem is Oracles doesn't support interval sub partitions.
Please advice how to achieve this scenario.

You can subpartition an interval - docs. You can't have a subpartition that is an interval, but that isn't what you seem to be describing. If you're trying say interval-hash partitioning and it's not working then show your code and the error you are getting. Though this is probably off-topic anyway as it's more of a DBA task than a programming task.
